# Is the set $\{(\frac{3}{2})^n - \lfloor(\frac{3}{2})^n\rfloor : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ dense in $[0,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis

The problem I want to solve is:

Is the set $\{(\frac{3}{2})^n - \lfloor(\frac{3}{2})^n\rfloor : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ dense in $[0,1]$? My assumption is no.

My reasoning:

1. $(\frac{3}{2})^n - \lfloor(\frac{3}{2})^n\rfloor$ can never exactly equal $0$.
2. Next I pick a number $a$ that is just "barely" larger than $0$.

Now i construct the open interval $(0,a)$.

Then I split $(\frac{3}{2})^n= \frac{3^n}{2^n}$ into two parts $\frac{2^n*x}{2^n} + \frac{y}{2^n}$ with $x$ being the integer part of $(\frac{3}{2})^n$. Now  I just need to prove:

$\frac{y}{2^n}>a$ for it not to be in the interval $(0,a)$ $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$.

Unfortunately, I am stuck here. Is my reasoning correct so far? Or will it lead to nothing?

Comment: You would have to prove that $\frac{y}{2^n}>a$ for *all* $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I am already aware of that. Sorry I didn't specify it, I will add it.

Comment: Which isn't true  for $a>0$...

Comment: Have you tried to graph the sequence ?

Comment: That's an open problem, so if you find something interesting, don't forget to tell us! :-) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html

Comment: Hint : How could you reach several irrational numbers with your sequence ? Which is different from $\{ u_n -u_m\}$ set very interesting in general.